# Question about automatic properties

Tags: c#-3.0, automatic-properties

what happens if you implement an automatic property

```
public string Foobar { get; set; }
```

and then code the corresponding variable

```
private string foobar = string.Empty;
```

Will the automatic property use this variable or does the compiler generate 
an additional variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the automatic property will not use your variable. It would be just like any other field called foobar.

The name smilarity does not influence the compiler in any way.

The compiler will generate a field behind the scenes but you do not have access to the backing field of the automatic property in any way.

[This post](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/03/03/c-3-0-automatic-properties-explained.aspx) shows how things work at the IL (Intermediate Langauge, Assembly of C#) level.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler won't use that variable, no. To use your variable you will have to write

```
private string foobar = string.Empty;

public string Foobar 
{
    get { return foobar; }
    set { foobar = value; }
}
```

If you have Resharper, you can set up templates to do this. Resharper will also generate a getter from an unused private variable for you.

Answer (score -1):

Why would it? Backing field doesn't have to be (and often isn't) named this way.

Comment: I mean, when you aren't using automatic properties. So you shouldn't always link names "Foobar" and "foobar" as "property - corresponding backing field" in your head.